# Let $E$ be measurable with $m(E)=1$. Show that there is a measurable set $F\subset E$ such that $m(F)=1/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be measurable with $m(E)=1$. Show that there is a measurable set $F\subset E$ such that $m(F)=1/2$. Hint: Consider the function $f(x) = m(E\cap(-\infty,x])$.

I've been working on this but it seems that I am completely stuck. I just started studying real analysis and so I do not have much experience yet but looking at the hint it seems to me I need to show that there is a $x_1$ or which the measure is lower than $1/2$ and one for which it is higher. Then use the continuity to confirm that there is an $x$ for which it takes the value $1/2$. However can't seem to find a way to start doing that. I would prefer hints over complete answers

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is with the Lebesgue measure, I assume?

Comment: Also works with a continuous probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I know, atom-free is sufficient. But I think OP should clarify that piece of the context.

Comment: This question has been answered several times before in MSE. Here is another  [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3684884/121671)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ and hence $f$ is continuous which means that we can use IVP to show that there must be an $x$ for which this function has measure $1/2$.

You don't have to *find* such $x_1$ and $x_2$. Just note that it is possible to find an in interval $[a,b]$ such that $m(E\cap [a,b])>\frac 12$. So, $f(a)<\frac 12$ and $f(b)>\frac 12$.

Comment: Note that the question also asks about how to find $x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1) \leq 1/2 \leq f(x_2)$.

Comment: @Sambo didn't notice it, thanks for pointing it out. Please see if the edit works.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that $f$ is continuous, and consider its limits at $\pm\infty$.